# xsd element generation jaxb

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am using maven to generate java classes from xsd. Below is the xsd.

```
<xsd:complexType name="BaseFaultType">

        <xsd:annotation>

            <xsd:documentation>A data type for a base fault.</xsd:documentation>

        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:complexContent>

            <xsd:extension base="wsrf-bf:BaseFaultType">

                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element ref="lexsmeta:MessageMetadata" minOccurs="0"/>

                </xsd:sequence>

            </xsd:extension>

        </xsd:complexContent>

    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="BusinessRuleNotMetFault" type="lexsfaults:BaseFaultType">

        <xsd:annotation>

            <xsd:documentation>A business rules not met fault (e.g. service provider requires *** in query, but query did not provide *** value).</xsd:documentation>

        </xsd:annotation>

    </xsd:element>
```

Java class are not generating for above element/s, does not throw any error too. May I know the reason or fix?

Comment: You did specify that namespaces `wsrf-bf` and `lexsfaults` should generate classes in different packages, right?

Comment: I have specified <packageName> element in pom.xml and all classes are generated in the same package including BaseFaultType. BusinessRuleNotMetFault did not generate.

Comment: So `wsrf-bf:BaseFaultType` and `lexsfaults:BaseFaultType` are both supposed to be created in the same package? You do know that you cannot have 2 different classes named `BaseFaultType` in a package, right? --- I mean, `<xsd:complexType name="` **`BaseFaultType`** `"> ... <xsd:complexContent><xsd:` **`extension`** `base="wsrf-bf:` **`BaseFaultType`** `">` (aka `class BaseFaultType extends BaseFaultType`) looks iffy to me.

Comment: Can I specify a different package using bindings file, ".xjb" file?

Comment: Why don't you check the manual to see what you can specify in a bindings file? You know, do some **research**. Learn something, so you know what is *possible*. Even if the answer is no, you'd learn something from doing the research.

Comment: Used bindings file and renamed one of the class in lexs-faults.xsd to LexsBaseFaultType and other class BaseFaultType, so no class collision. But still BusinessRuleNotMetFault java file is not generated. Any idea?